# Postman $GUID: Remove hyphens and make all character uppercase

Tags: javascript, postman, guid

Can someone help me to remove the hyphens and transform all characters to uppercase (from a postman `$guid`)?

Haven't find anything useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many hacky ways to do this in Postman, here's one of them:

```
let guid = pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$guid}}')

let formattedGuid = guid.replace(/-/g, '').toUpperCase()

pm.globals.set("newGuid", formattedGuid)
```

If you add that to the `Pre-request Script`, you'll be able to use it in the requests.

Comment: What language is this? Would you mind updating the question's tagging appropriately (assuming postman is language-specific)?

Comment: Postman is a tool written in JS, the `Pre-request Script` and `Tests` sandbox environment allow you to use JS do well....whatever you want. It also has it's own `pm.*` API with certain Postman specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the new postman guid generator {{newGuid}}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34996849)